# Error of importing data from txt file to IBM netezza SQL database due to date format

Tags: database, date-format, netezza

I need to upload data from a **text file** to the **Netezza** table. It is not working because date format is not same between the Netezza table and Text file. As per Netezza table date format which should be date only but in text file it is datetime.

Is there any way, so that I can convert the datatime into date only while uploading.

1. Below is the file format with one row of data -

**AS_OF_DATE|ID

10/01/2015 00:00:00|40**

2. Below Netezza query I am using to upload

INSERT INTO 
LND_FINANCE_CUSTOMER
(AS_OF_DATE,ID)

SELECT 
*
FROM EXTERNAL 'D:123.txt'

USING (
QUOTEDVALUE DOUBLE
DELIMITER '|'
MAXERRORS 4 
DATESTYLE MDY
DATEDELIM '/'
MAXROWS 0 
Y2BASE 2000 
ENCODING internal
REMOTESOURCE ODBC
ESCAPECHAR '\');

3. 0 Rows are inserting because of date format. If in the text file I manually change the datetime format into date only. then it is working fine.

Comment: Where is the query ans file format you are talking about

Comment: Is the AS_OF_DATE column in the LND_FINANCE_CUSTOMER table on  Netezza defined as DATE or TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 1):

If you force the file specification to timestamp the load should work fine.  It will cast back to a date on the insert into `LND_FINANCE_CUSTOMER`.  See Code Below:

```
    INSERT INTO LND_FINANCE_CUSTOMER (AS_OF_DATE,ID)

    SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'D:\123.txt'
(AS_OF_DATE  timestamp
        ,ID  integer)    
    USING ( QUOTEDVALUE DOUBLE DELIMITER '|' MAXERRORS 4 DATESTYLE MDY DATEDELIM '/' MAXROWS 0 Y2BASE 2000 ENCODING internal REMOTESOURCE ODBC ESCAPECHAR '\');
```